# Finding isometries of a Banach Spaces.

Tags: hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, isometry

Given a Hilbert Space $(H,\langle,\rangle)$, $x,y\in H$ and $D\subset H$ a subspace of $H$ (I mean, the operators $+$, $\cdot$ and $\langle,\rangle$ in D are the restrictions of the respective ones in $H$), the fact that there exists an isometry $f:H\to H$ such that $f(x)=y$ and $f(z)=z$ for every $z\in D$ is characterized by having $\|x\|=\|y\|$ and $Proy_D(x)=Proy_D (y)$.

Is there any way to get a similar characterization in general Banach Spaces?

Thanks.

Comment: One can always define some special kind of spaces and write down some uninteresting consequences of the definition. In that sense the answer is "yes".

Comment: I do not think this is an "uninteresting" consequence because it is related to the fact that x and y have the same (model-theoretical) behavior relative to a closed subspace of a Banach Space, via a Galois analysis. Anyway, thanks a lot for your time answering my question.